# Mutiple SELECTs against the same table, but with different ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, select, union

I'd like to fetch data from the same table, but ordered by 2 different fields, based on the value of a third field

i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Status = 0
ORDER BY SortOrder

UNION

SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Status = 1
ORDER BY ModifiedAt DESC
```

Of course, I can't have 2 ORDER BYs in a UNION, so wondering if there is a better (performance-wise) way without having to resort to 2 database queries - perhaps via a subquery of some sort?

Comment: You want the same data twice in your results, just ordered differently?

Comment: Are you trying to sort by SortOrder then ModifiedAt or do you really want the same data in there sorted two different ways?

Comment: No, each query returns a subset, because of the filter by 'Status'. I need to display both sets of data separately in the same view, but trying to avoid 2 queries

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid two queries when that seems like exactly what you want...?

Comment: @AdamRobinson, just trying to see if its possible to do it with 1 query - wouldn't that be better as its 1 less roundtrip to the db?

Comment: You're looking for two different sets of data. Use two queries. Hoofbeats and zebras and all that :)

Comment: :) You may be right - I'm probably over-thinking it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` in the order by

```
select *
from YourTable
where Status in (0, 1)
order by Status,
         case when Status = 0 then SortOrder end,
         ModifiedAt desc
```